# Could not load file or assembly error even when reference has been removed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

`Could not load file or assembly 'Payflow_dotNET_2.0' or one of its dependencies. The  located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`

I've currently *removed all references* to the `Payflow SDK`, though I still get this error. Is there anything else I need to do to get the project to compile and run?

Comment: Is it configured in your web.config somewhere? (like a prefix or something similar)

Comment: There is nothing in my web.config that that has Payflow_dotNET_2.0

Comment: So now what's left is to remove all referenced assemblies from your MVC application that have a reference to this assembly.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov  I can't do that because I referenced this payflow assembly in my service assembly the the entire project is using.

Comment: @twal, so you should modify this service assembly to remove references or live happily with the error message.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, this is my problem I have removed the payflow reference from my service assembly. It is no longer in the the list of references. This is my problem and why I don't know why I am still getting this error.

Comment: @twal you are getting the exception because you still have an assembly which is referencing it. It's as simple as that. There are no miracles.

Comment: @twal, I will indeed refrain myself from posting, I apologize if my comments sounded like a condescending tone. But really, what kind of answer to you expect to such a question? I mean you are getting an error that an assembly cannot be loaded and you are saying that you have removed all references to it and you code never uses it. I mean I don't know what kind of answer do you really expect to such a question.

Comment: @twal, the problem is that we cannot help you because we don't have your project, we don't know where you might be referencing this assembly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something in your project is still referencing that assembly.  It might be in the web.config or a the project file itself.

Go look in ALL of the the .csproj files that make up your solution and search for "payflow".  You might even just do a search in files (using your favorite tool of choice) and look for it.

**UPDATE**
Just trying to understand here.  It sounds like you have a main project which references some other "service" assembly.  Initially you added the payflow reference to this second assembly (and your primary project?).

You said you then removed it from both the main project and the service assembly.  Correct?  Did you refresh the reference from the main project to the service assembly?

Comment: Thank you very much. I did an in file search as you recommended and Payflow was found in the debug folder in a file called ResolveAssemblyReference.cache. I deleted this file started it again and it worked. Thanks for helping I really appreciate it!

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly. I did refresh the reference in the main project to the service assembly and still got that error. Once I found the cache file and removed it all worked fine. Not sure why that was not getting updated. I even did a clean on the project. But once i deleted the cache file it started just fine with no error.

Comment: @twal:  Awesome.  Glad that worked out for you.  I love how studio "caches" all of these files.

Answer (score 8):

Had the same issue.

Even after removing any reference of a library from the project (which was stored in a totally different location), the error still persisted.

The problem actually was that the .dll was still present in the 'bin' folder of the application.

Just had to remove it from there and everything went fine.

Hope it helps somebody, someday.

Comment: I assumed rebuild which also runs a clean would clean it for me but I guess not. This was also my issue.

Comment: @JamesBlackburn Exactly the same for me, after and rebuilding countless times, the sole persistence of the dll in the bin folder did that. There's definitely something rotten in the kingdom of visualStudio...